# Unenviable duplication of code in C#

Tags: c#, generics, task-parallel-library

I have the following simple method in C#:

```
private static void ExtendTaskInternal<U>(
    ref U task_to_update, U replace, Action a) where U : Task 
{
    var current = Interlocked.Exchange(ref task_to_update, replace);
    if (current == null)
        Task.Run(a);
    else
        current.AppendAction(a);
}
```

This is used for the following methods:

```
//A Task can only run once. But sometimes we wanted to have a reference to some 
//tasks that can be restarted. Of cause, in this case "restart" a task means 
//replace the reference with a new one. To safely do so we have to ensure a 
//lot of things:
//
//   * Would the referee be null?
//   * Is it still running?
//   * The replacement of the task must be atomic
//
//This method can help solving the above issues. If `task_to_update` is null,
//a new Task will be created to replace it. If it is already there, a new Task
//will be created as its continuation, which will only run when the previous 
//one finishes.
//
//This is looks like a async mutex, since if you assume `ExtendTask` is the only
//function in your code that updates `task_to_update`, the delegates you pass to 
//it runs sequentially. But the difference is that since you have a reference to
//a Task, you can attach continuations that receive notification of lock 
//releases.
public static Task<T> ExtendTask<T>(ref Task<T> task_to_update, Func<T> func)
{
    var next_ts = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    ExtendTaskInternal(ref task_to_update, next_ts.Task, 
        () => next_ts.SetResult(func()));
    return next_ts.Task;
}
```

If you want to do something but only after something else have already been done, this is useful.

Now, this version can only used to replace a `Task<T>`, not a `Task` since `ref` variables are invariant. So if you want it to work for `Task` as well you have to duplicate the code:

```
public static Task<T> ExtendTask<T>(ref Task task_to_update, Func<T> func)
{
    var next_ts = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    ExtendTaskInternal(ref task_to_update, next_ts.Task, 
        () => next_ts.SetResult(func()));
    return next_ts.Task;
}
```

And so you can implement another version that works on `Action`s.

```
public static Task ExtendTask(ref Task task_to_update, Action a)
{
    return ExtendTask(ref task_to_update, () =>
    {
        a();
        return true;
    });
}
```

So far so good. But I don't like the first and the second version of the `ExtendTask`, since the body looks exactly the same.

Are there any way to eliminate the duplication?

**Background**

People ask why not use `ContinueWith`.

First, notice that `AppendAction` is just a wrapper function (from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading`) of `ContinueWith` so this code is already using it indirectly.

Second, What I did differently here is that I have a reference to update, so this is another wrapper function to `ContinueWith`, the purpose of those functions is to make it easier to use in some scenarios.

I provide the following concrete example (untested) to illustrate the usage of those methods.

```
public class Cat {
    private Task miuTask = null;

    //you have to finish a miu to start another...
    private void DoMiu(){
         //... do what ever required to "miu".
    }

    public Task MiuAsync(){

        return MyTaskExtension.ExtendTask(ref miuTask, DoMiu);

    }

    public void RegisterMiuListener(Action whenMiued){

        var current = miuTask;
        if(current==null) current = TplExtensions.CompletedTask();
        current.AppendAction(whenMiued);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing things this way rather than using `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @EarthEngine, it would be more helpful if you preceded your code with a few words about what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have done so by adding comments to the code.